# SQL- selecting two id's who share something in common

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that has player_id, team_id

I want to find all players who played on the same 3 or more teams.

The expected output would be :

player1, player2, number_of_teams

so far i have something like

```
SELECT player_id as player1, player_id as player2, count(team_id) as number_of_teams
FROM player_history
WHERE ....
```

Sample Data:

```
player_id | team_id 
--------------------
001       | 23 
001       | 15
001       | 21 
002       | 23 
002       | 21
002       | 15
002       | 34 
003       | 23 
003       | 15
003       | 34 
003       | 21 
004       | 12 
004       | 11 
004       | 23
```

should return:

```
player1 | player2 | number_of_teams
 -----------------------------------
001 | 002 | 3
001 | 003 | 3
002 | 003 | 4
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?that really help

Comment: What's the different between player1 and player2?

Comment: What about there are more than two plays, who join over three team?

Comment: updated the data/output

Comment: you dont have a pattern, the query you want will NOT output exactly what you want.

Comment: How is there not a pattern? two ids with 3 or more common team id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is join your table with itself, on the same team but different players, once found, you should group the result table and count

Since I *assume* there's more than 2 players in each team *and* you're looking for different players in the same *year* as implied (not really specified) in your question, I took the liberty to add it to the join conditions
You can, of course, remove it

```
    SELECT
     p1, 
     p2, 
     COUNT(team_id) as total

     FROM
    (

          SELECT
          h1.team_id,
             h1.player_id as p1, 
             h2.player_id as p2
            FROM
             player_history h1
             INNER JOIN player_history h2 ON h1.team_id = h2.team_id AND h1.player_id != h2.player_id AND h1.year = h2.year
            GROUP BY
             h1.team_id,
 h1.player_id
           ) sameteam

    GROUP BY
    p1, 
    p2
    HAVING
    total >= 3
```

Notice that your example result doesn't fit the example data. play 4 should not be on the list

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b0114/6)
hope it helps

Comment: yea i killed the year column for this example

Comment: so you can remove the last join condition

Comment: im marking it as correct, but i have not yet tested

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, that won't work (because of the GROUP BY clause for sure).

Comment: should be nested

Comment: It is still wrong. Besides, even when you fix that, it'll return "duplicates", i.e. pairs (001, 003) and (003, 001) which are, actually, the same two players in both cases.

Comment: Certainly, @Jacob. But he did not. Somewhat strange for an *accepted^ solution.

Comment: strange... you don't look for the smaller id but for the different id, more than that, it should get more results, not less or none